# Homekit turns on light with a scene

Tags: ios, homekit

I have setup IKEA Tradfri lights. I have the bridge and set everything up in HomeKit. I have a bunch of different scenes and automations.

One automation triggers a scene which sets the brightness and color temperature of the lights when the sun is rising. The scene looks like this in the Non-Apple Home.app.

[image: Scene Scree Capture]

The problem is, sometimes the lights get **turned on** with this scene, which should not happen. I can't clearly see a pattern, which light will be affected. Usually I would say, it is the last light, which was on, for example, a at night dimmed light in the hallway.

Is this a known bug or is something setup wrong? What are my options to troubleshoot?

Comment: You say the lights get "turned on."  They're all set to 80% brightness which means "**they're turned on** to 80% brighness."  Do you mean the brightness setting isn't working (i.e. they're turning on at 100% not 80% as programmed)? Secondly, you need to continue diagnosing - confirm whether or not it's the "last light" as you surmised.  Remember, we're not there and can't do the testing for you.

Comment: No, setting the brightness to 80% does not mean turn on the lights! This is possible to set up with different HomeKit Apps and a officially support feature. It is just not available to set up in Apple own Home.app. If I turn on the scene manually, everything works as aspected.